MAUI Dependecy Error In AndroidManifest.xml
while tring adding push notification to MAUI android app i started to encounter di error and i can't resolve it, i tried asking ChatGPT several times but it didn't help a lot,i tried adding android:export like chatgpt said but nothing but with this error i can't load my app if anyone could help it would be very helpful!
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.example.amadaapp">

<!-- Permessi necessari -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:targetApi="28">

    <!-- Configurazione di Firebase Messaging -->
    <service
        android:name=".FirebaseMessagingService"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <!-- Configurazione Firebase Instance ID -->
    <service
        android:name=".FirebaseInstanceIdService"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <!-- Configurazione Firebase Remote Config -->
    <service
        android:name="com.google.firebase.remoteconfig.FirebaseRemoteConfigService"
        android:exported="false" />

    <!-- Configurazione Firebase Analytics -->
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.firebase.analytics.AnalyticsReceiver"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action      android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <!-- Ricezione delle notifiche all'avvio del dispositivo -->
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.example.amadaapp" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <!-- Configurazione per Firebase Crashlytics -->
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.analytics.AnalyticsReceiver"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <!-- Definizione dell'activity principale -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.microsoft.maui.MauiAppCompatActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>

</manifest>

`
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    K 
Suppression State
Error (active)  AMM0000 C:\Users\manue\source\repos\AmadaApp- 
master\AmadaApp\obj\Debug\net8.0- 
android\lp\277\jl\AndroidManifest.xml Warning:
Namespace 'com.google.firebase.abt' used in: 
AndroidManifest.xml, AndroidManifest.xml.
C:\Users\manue\source\repos\AmadaApp- 
master\AmadaApp\obj\Debug\net8.0- 
android\lp\315\jl\AndroidManifest.xml Warning:
Namespace 'com.google.android.gms.ads_identifier' used in: 
AndroidManifest.xml, AndroidManifest.xml.
C:\Users\manue\source\repos\AmadaApp- 
master\AmadaApp\obj\Debug\net8.0- 
android\lp\290\jl\AndroidManifest.xml Warning:
Namespace 'com.google.firebase.database.collection' used in: 
AndroidManifest.xml, AndroidManifest.xml.
C:\Users\manue\source\repos\AmadaApp- 
master\AmadaApp\obj\Debug\net8.0- 
android\lp\300\jl\AndroidManifest.xml Warning:
Namespace 'com.google.firebase.installations' used in: 
AndroidManifest.xml, AndroidManifest.xml.
C:\Users\manue\source\repos\AmadaApp- 
master\AmadaApp\obj\Debug\net8.0- 
android\lp\288\jl\AndroidManifest.xml Warning:
Namespace 'com.google.firebase.firebase_core' used in: 
AndroidManifest.xml, AndroidManifest.xml.
C:\Users\manue\source\repos\AmadaApp- 
master\AmadaApp\obj\Debug\net8.0- 
android\lp\307\jl\AndroidManifest.xml Warning:
Namespace 'com.google.firebase.storage' used in: 
AndroidManifest.xml, AndroidManifest.xml.
C:\Users\manue\source\repos\AmadaApp- 
master\AmadaApp\obj\Debug\net8.0- 
android\lp\292\jl\AndroidManifest.xml Warning:
Namespace 'com.google.firebase.dynamiclinks' used in: 
AndroidManifest.xml, AndroidManifest.xml.
C:\Users\manue\source\repos\AmadaApp- 
master\AmadaApp\obj\Debug\net8.0- 
android\lp\297\jl\AndroidManifest.xml Warning:
Namespace 'com.google.firebase.functions' used in: 
AndroidManifest.xml, AndroidManifest.xml.
C:\Users\manue\source\repos\AmadaApp- 
master\AmadaApp\obj\Debug\net8.0- 
android\lp\325\jl\AndroidManifest.xml Warning:
Namespace 'com.google.android.gms.measurement.sdk.api' used in: 
AndroidManifest.xml, AndroidManifest.xml.
C:\Users\manue\source\repos\AmadaApp- 
master\AmadaApp\obj\Debug\net8.0- 
android\lp\326\jl\AndroidManifest.xml Warning:
Namespace 'com.google.android.gms.measurement.sdk' used in: 
AndroidManifest.xml, AndroidManifest.xml.
C:\Users\manue\source\repos\AmadaApp- 
master\AmadaApp\obj\Debug\net8.0- 
android\lp\291\jl\AndroidManifest.xml Warning:
Namespace 'com.google.firebase.datatransport' used in: 
AndroidManifest.xml, AndroidManifest.xml.
C:\Users\manue\source\repos\AmadaApp- 
master\AmadaApp\obj\Debug\net8.0- 
android\lp\302\jl\AndroidManifest.xml Warning:
Namespace 'com.google.firebase.analytics.connector' used in: 
AndroidManifest.xml, AndroidManifest.xml.
C:\Users\manue\source\repos\AmadaApp- 
master\AmadaApp\obj\Debug\net8.0- 
android\lp\298\jl\AndroidManifest.xml Warning:
Namespace 'com.google.firebase.iid' used in: 
AndroidManifest.xml, AndroidManifest.xml.
C:\Users\manue\source\repos\AmadaApp- 
master\AmadaApp\obj\Debug\net8.0- 
android\lp\283\jl\AndroidManifest.xml Warning:
Namespace 'com.google.firebase' used in: AndroidManifest.xml, 
AndroidManifest.xml.
C:\Users\manue\source\repos\AmadaApp- 
master\AmadaApp\obj\Debug\net8.0- 
android\lp\294\jl\AndroidManifest.xml Warning:
Namespace 'com.google.firebase.encoders.json' used in: 
AndroidManifest.xml, AndroidManifest.xml.
C:\Users\manue\source\repos\AmadaApp- 
master\AmadaApp\obj\Debug\net8.0- 
android\lp\301\jl\AndroidManifest.xml Warning:
Namespace 'com.google.firebase.installations.interop' used in: 
AndroidManifest.xml, AndroidManifest.xml.
C:\Users\manue\source\repos\AmadaApp- 
master\AmadaApp\obj\Debug\net8.0- 
android\lp\303\jl\AndroidManifest.xml Warning:
Namespace 'com.google.firebase.messaging' used in: 
AndroidManifest.xml, AndroidManifest.xml.
C:\Users\manue\source\repos\AmadaApp- 
master\AmadaApp\obj\Debug\net8.0- 
android\lp\319\jl\AndroidManifest.xml Warning:
Namespace 'com.google.android.gms.cloudmessaging' used in: 
AndroidManifest.xml, AndroidManifest.xml.
C:\Users\manue\source\repos\AmadaApp- 
master\AmadaApp\obj\Debug\net8.0- 
android\lp\296\jl\AndroidManifest.xml Warning:
Namespace 'com.google.firebase.firestore' used in: 
AndroidManifest.xml, AndroidManifest.xml.
C:\Users\manue\source\repos\AmadaApp- 
master\AmadaApp\obj\Debug\net8.0- 
android\lp\321\jl\AndroidManifest.xml Warning:
Namespace 'com.google.android.gms.measurement.api' used in: 
AndroidManifest.xml, AndroidManifest.xml.
C:\Users\manue\source\repos\AmadaApp- 
master\AmadaApp\obj\Debug\net8.0- 
android\lp\304\jl\AndroidManifest.xml Warning:
Namespace 'firebase.com.protolitewrapper' used in: 
AndroidManifest.xml, AndroidManifest.xml.
C:\Users\manue\source\repos\AmadaApp- 
master\AmadaApp\obj\Debug\net8.0- 
android\lp\286\jl\AndroidManifest.xml Warning:
Namespace 'com.google.firebase.remoteconfig' used in: 
AndroidManifest.xml, AndroidManifest.xml.
C:\Users\manue\source\repos\AmadaApp- 
master\AmadaApp\obj\Debug\net8.0- 
android\lp\318\jl\AndroidManifest.xml Warning:
Namespace 'com.google.android.gms.common' used in: 
AndroidManifest.xml, AndroidManifest.xml.
C:\Users\manue\source\repos\AmadaApp- 
master\AmadaApp\obj\Debug\net8.0- 
android\lp\329\jl\AndroidManifest.xml Warning:
Namespace 'com.google.android.gms.tasks' used in: 
AndroidManifest.xml, AndroidManifest.xml.
C:\Users\manue\source\repos\AmadaApp- 
master\AmadaApp\obj\Debug\net8.0- 
android\lp\323\jl\AndroidManifest.xml Warning:
Namespace 'com.google.firebase.measurement' used in: 
AndroidManifest.xml, AndroidManifest.xml.
C:\Users\manue\source\repos\AmadaApp- 
master\AmadaApp\obj\Debug\net8.0- 
android\lp\281\jl\AndroidManifest.xml Warning:
Namespace 'com.google.firebase.auth' used in: 

AndroidManifest.xml, AndroidManifest.xml.
C:\Users\manue\source\repos\AmadaApp- 
master\AmadaApp\obj\Debug\net8.0- 
android\lp\324\jl\AndroidManifest.xml Warning:
    Namespace 'com.google.firebase.measurement_impl' used in: 
AndroidManifest.xml, AndroidManifest.xml.
C:\Users\manue\source\repos\AmadaApp- 
master\AmadaApp\obj\Debug\net8.0- 
android\lp\306\jl\AndroidManifest.xml Warning:
    Namespace 'com.google.firebase.storage.common' used in: 
AndroidManifest.xml, AndroidManifest.xml.
C:\Users\manue\source\repos\AmadaApp- 
master\AmadaApp\obj\Debug\net8.0- 
android\lp\305\jl\AndroidManifest.xml Warning:
    Namespace 'com.google.firebase.sessions' used in: 
AndroidManifest.xml, AndroidManifest.xml.
C:\Users\manue\source\repos\AmadaApp- 
master\AmadaApp\obj\Debug\net8.0- 
android\lp\328\jl\AndroidManifest.xml Warning:
    Namespace 'com.google.android.gms.stats' used in: 
AndroidManifest.xml, AndroidManifest.xml.
C:\Users\manue\source\repos\AmadaApp- 
master\AmadaApp\obj\Debug\net8.0- 
android\lp\282\jl\AndroidManifest.xml Warning:
    Namespace 'com.google.firebase.auth.internal' used in: 
AndroidManifest.xml, AndroidManifest.xml.
C:\Users\manue\source\repos\AmadaApp- 
master\AmadaApp\obj\Debug\net8.0- 
android\lp\285\jl\AndroidManifest.xml Warning:
    Namespace 'com.google.firebase.components' used in: 
AndroidManifest.xml, AndroidManifest.xml.
C:\Users\manue\source\repos\AmadaApp- 
master\AmadaApp\obj\Debug\net8.0- 
android\lp\287\jl\AndroidManifest.xml Warning:
    Namespace 'com.google.firebase.remoteconfiginterop' used 
in: AndroidManifest.xml, AndroidManifest.xml.
C:\Users\manue\source\repos\AmadaApp- 
master\AmadaApp\obj\Debug\net8.0- 
android\lp\316\jl\AndroidManifest.xml Warning:
    Namespace 'com.google.android.gms.auth.api.phone' used in: 
AndroidManifest.xml, AndroidManifest.xml.
C:\Users\manue\source\repos\AmadaApp- 
master\AmadaApp\obj\Debug\net8.0- 
android\lp\317\jl\AndroidManifest.xml Warning:
    Namespace 'com.google.android.gms.base' used in: 
AndroidManifest.xml, AndroidManifest.xml.
C:\Users\manue\source\repos\AmadaApp- 
master\AmadaApp\obj\Debug\net8.0- 
android\lp\280\jl\AndroidManifest.xml Warning:
    Namespace 'com.google.firebase.appcheck.interop' used in: 
AndroidManifest.xml, AndroidManifest.xml.
C:\Users\manue\source\repos\AmadaApp- 
master\AmadaApp\obj\Debug\net8.0- 
android\lp\284\jl\AndroidManifest.xml Warning:
    Namespace 'com.google.firebase.ktx' used in: 
AndroidManifest.xml, AndroidManifest.xml.
C:\Users\manue\source\repos\AmadaApp- 
master\AmadaApp\obj\Debug\net8.0- 
android\lp\289\jl\AndroidManifest.xml Warning:
    Namespace 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics' used in: 
AndroidManifest.xml, AndroidManifest.xml.
C:\Users\manue\source\repos\AmadaApp- 
master\AmadaApp\obj\Debug\net8.0- 
android\lp\322\jl\AndroidManifest.xml Warning:
    Namespace 'com.google.android.gms.measurement_base' used 
in: AndroidManifest.xml, AndroidManifest.xml.
C:\Users\manue\source\repos\AmadaApp- 
master\AmadaApp\obj\Debug\net8.0- 
android\lp\278\jl\AndroidManifest.xml Warning:
    Namespace 'com.google.firebase.firebase_analytics' used in: 
AndroidManifest.xml, AndroidManifest.xml.
C:\Users\manue\source\repos\AmadaApp- 
master\AmadaApp\obj\Debug\net8.0- 
android\lp\320\jl\AndroidManifest.xml Warning:
    Namespace 'com.google.android.gms.location' used in: 
AndroidManifest.xml, AndroidManifest.xml.
C:\Users\manue\source\repos\AmadaApp- 
master\AmadaApp\obj\Debug\net8.0- 
android\lp\299\jl\AndroidManifest.xml Warning:
    Namespace 'com.google.firebase.iid.internal' used in: 
AndroidManifest.xml, AndroidManifest.xml.
C:\Users\manue\source\repos\AmadaApp- 
 master\AmadaApp\obj\Debug\net8.0- 
 android\lp\327\jl\AndroidManifest.xml Warning:
    Namespace 'com.google.android.gms.safetynet' used in: 
 AndroidManifest.xml, AndroidManifest.xml.

    android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element 
<service#crc649aaf9c208817d9c3.FirebaseService>. Apps targeting 
Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value 
for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an 
intent filter defined. See 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity- 
element#exported for details.
Directory 'obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\277' is from 'firebase- 
abt.aar'.
Directory 'obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\315' is from 'play- 
services-ads-identifier.aar'.
Directory 'obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\290' is from 'firebase- 
database-collection.aar'.
Directory 'obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\300' is from 'firebase- 
installations.aar'.
Directory 'obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\288' is from 'firebase- 
core.aar'.
Directory 'obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\307' is from 'firebase- 
storage.aar'.
Directory 'obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\292' is from 'firebase- 
dynamic-links.aar'.
Directory 'obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\297' is from 'firebase- 
functions.aar'.
Directory 'obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\325' is from 'play- 
services-measurement-sdk-api.aar'.
Directory 'obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\326' is from 'play- 
services-measurement-sdk.aar'.
Directory 'obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\291' is from 'firebase- 
datatransport.aar'.
Directory 'obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\302' is from 'firebase- 
measurement-connector.aar'.
Directory 'obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\298' is from 'firebase- 
iid.aar'.
Directory 'obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\283' is from 'firebase- 
common.aar'.
Directory 'obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\294' is from 'firebase- 
encoders-json.aar'.
Directory 'obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\301' is from 'firebase- 
installations-interop.aar'.
Directory 'obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\303' is from 'firebase- 
messaging.aar'.
Directory 'obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\319' is from 'play-services-cloud-messaging.aar'.
Directory 'obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\296' is from 'firebase-firestore.aar'.
Directory 'obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\321' is from 'play-services-measurement-api.aar'.
Directory 'obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\304' is from 'protolite-well-known-types.aar'.
Directory 'obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\286' is from 'firebase-config.aar'.
Directory 'obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\318' is from 'play-services-basement.aar'.
Directory 'obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\329' is from 'play-services-tasks.aar'.
Directory 'obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\323' is from 'play-services-measurement.aar'.
Directory 'obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\281' is from 'firebase-auth.aar'.
Directory 'obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\324' is from 'play-services-measurement-impl.aar'.
Directory 'obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\306' is from 'firebase-storage-common.aar'.
Directory 'obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\305' is from 'firebase-sessions.aar'.
Directory 'obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\328' is from 'play-services-stats.aar'.
Directory 'obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\282' is from 'firebase-auth-interop.aar'.
Directory 'obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\285' is from 'firebase-components.aar'.
Directory 'obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\287' is from 'firebase-config-interop.aar'.
Directory 'obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\316' is from 'play-services-auth-api-phone.aar'.
Directory 'obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\317' is from 'play-services-base.aar'.
Directory 'obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\280' is from 'firebase-appcheck-interop.aar'. 
Directory 'obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\284' is from 'firebase-common-ktx.aar'.
Directory 'obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\289' is from 'firebase-crashlytics.aar'.
Directory 'obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\322' is from 'play-services-measurement-base.aar'.
Directory 'obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\278' is from 'firebase-analytics.aar'.
Directory 'obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\320' is from 'play-services-location.aar'.
Directory 'obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\299' is from 'firebase-iid-interop.aar'.
Directory 'obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\327' is from 'play-services-safetynet.aar'.  AmadaApp (net8.0-android)   C:\Users\manue\source\repos\AmadaApp-master\AmadaApp\obj\Debug\net8.0-android\AndroidManifest.xml   64  


what is the error?

it's in the link i added

please read [ask].  Errors and code should be included in the body of the post, properly formatted.  The link you posted leads to some adware infested site

i added the error

You can try to use ActivityAttribute instead of some of the node content in Manifest, such as the service, activity nodes.For more information,please refer to Manifest.

It seems to be complaining about the intent filter you set on line 49 and 70.
<action android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver" />

I suggest that you stop listening to ChatGPT and start reading the documentation and getting started guide.
